# Android Studio jdk location problem?

Tags: jdk, android-studio

I had installed android studio and jdk8 on Ubuntu. when I open android studio its show me a jdk location error. When I was open the location it shows me  `/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386`, but I installed jdk8. So how can I set the android studio jdk location to the jdk8 location?
I ran `echo $JAVA_HOME` and it shows me `/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386`. I also performed these two commands:

- `java -version`: java version "1.8.0_65"
- `javac -version`: javac version "1.8.0_65"

So how do I set my jdk location to the jdk8 location?

Comment: Thanks for updating correct format i will keep in mind before ask any question next time.

Answer (score 0):

Followning this [source](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-java-on-ubuntu-with-apt-get).

- `sudo update-alternatives --config java` for switch version Javas.
  After switch you should update your JAVA_HOME.
- `sudo nano /etc/environment`
  Add your last line or edit `JAVA_HOME="YOUR_PATH"`. With `YOUR_PATH`      you can see from `sudo update-alternatives --config java`
- After update `JAVA_HOME` , run `source /etc/environment` to finish update.

Anyway this question should mark a duplicate.

Comment: @Akydev if this is your answer you looking for please mark it done!

Comment: I don't know. After perform all this its work but I think there is mismatch of path and now my computer went to the login window loop and I am not able to login. It's redirect me again and again at login window.

Comment: i don't think java make you that, please post a question about your loop login

Comment: I already posted but there is no solution. I am not able to login from the morning and I am suffering from it and try to find proper solutions. I perform cmd as people told me in the answer. But still same. You can see that at my question. Ubuntu v14.04 login problem ?

Comment: Please provide more information about your Question login. Add this line "after I switched my java location via `sudo aupdate-alternatives --config java`".

Comment: I can not able to login in my computer so I can not perform cmd as you told me. I recently post a question that : Ubuntu V14. 04 login problem ? Please visit that and if you understand something help me to come out of this.